# how can i transform this using keys

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm able to write a horribly bad xslt without using keys but it's quite slow and messy. Does anyone know how i would transform the following XML file into the expected result cleanly? Thanks!

input:

```
<testExecution>
    <test>
        <test.1/>
        <test.2/>
        <test.3/>
    </test>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <executor>
        <executor.1/>
        <executor.2/>
        <executor.3/>
    </executor>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <invoker>
        <invoker.1/>
        <invoker.2/>
        <invoker.3/>
    </invoker>
    <recipient>
        <recipient.1/>
        <recipient.2/>
        <recipient.3/>
    </recipient>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
</testExecution>
```

result:

```
<testExecution>
    <test>
        <test.1/>
        <test.2/>
        <test.3/>
    </test>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <people>
        <importantPeople>
            <executor>
                <executor.1/>
                <executor.2/>
                <executor.3/>
            </executor>
            <comment>
                <comment.1/>
                <comment.2/>
                <comment.3/>
            </comment>
            <comment>
                <comment.1/>
                <comment.2/>
                <comment.3/>
            </comment>
        </importantPeople>
        <invoker>
            <invoker.1/>
            <invoker.2/>
            <invoker.3/>
        </invoker>
    </people>
    <recipient>
        <recipient.1/>
        <recipient.2/>
        <recipient.3/>
    </recipient>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
</testExecution>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a traditional XSLT solution using and overriding the identity rule and using keys for the following `comments`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kElementByTest" match="invoker|recipient"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::test[1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="executor">
        <xsl:variable name="vFollowing"
                      select="key('kElementByTest',
                                  generate-id(preceding-sibling::test[1]))"/>
        <people>
            <importantPeople>
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </importantPeople>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$vFollowing/self::invoker"
                                     mode="copy"/>
        </people>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vFollowing/self::recipient"
                             mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="invoker"/>
    <xsl:template match="recipient"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<testExecution>
    <test>
        <test.1></test.1>
        <test.2></test.2>
        <test.3></test.3>
    </test>
    <comment>
        <comment.1></comment.1>
        <comment.2></comment.2>
        <comment.3></comment.3>
    </comment>
    <people>
        <importantPeople>
            <executor>
                <executor.1></executor.1>
                <executor.2></executor.2>
                <executor.3></executor.3>
            </executor>
            <comment>
                <comment.1></comment.1>
                <comment.2></comment.2>
                <comment.3></comment.3>
            </comment>
            <comment>
                <comment.1></comment.1>
                <comment.2></comment.2>
                <comment.3></comment.3>
            </comment>
        </importantPeople>
        <invoker>
            <invoker.1></invoker.1>
            <invoker.2></invoker.2>
            <invoker.3></invoker.3>
        </invoker>
    </people>
    <recipient>
        <recipient.1></recipient.1>
        <recipient.2></recipient.2>
        <recipient.3></recipient.3>
    </recipient>
    <comment>
        <comment.1></comment.1>
        <comment.2></comment.2>
        <comment.3></comment.3>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1></comment.1>
        <comment.2></comment.2>
        <comment.3></comment.3>
    </comment>
</testExecution>
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal. Keys for "just for this test" followings. Empty templates for "close this level". Mode for push style "keep processing". It could be full "pull style" matching "the previus before the mark".

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation** uses and overrides the identity rule. Comments immediately following `executor` are retrieved using the `key()` function. `executor` , `invoker` and `comment` immediately following `executor` are copied in special *mode* named `people`. In the usual, anonymous mode these are matched by an empty template to avoid copying them a second time:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kExecComments" match=
  "comment
          [preceding-sibling::*
              [not(self::comment)][1]
                       [self::executor]
          ]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::executor[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="executor">
  <people>
    <importantPeople>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="people"
        select=".|key('kExecComments', generate-id())"/>
    </importantPeople>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="people" select=
    "following-sibling::invoker"/>
  </people>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="executor|comment|invoker"
      mode="people">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "invoker |
   comment
          [preceding-sibling::*
              [not(self::comment)][1]
                       [self::executor]
          ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<testExecution>
    <test>
        <test.1/>
        <test.2/>
        <test.3/>
    </test>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <executor>
        <executor.1/>
        <executor.2/>
        <executor.3/>
    </executor>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <invoker>
        <invoker.1/>
        <invoker.2/>
        <invoker.3/>
    </invoker>
    <recipient>
        <recipient.1/>
        <recipient.2/>
        <recipient.3/>
    </recipient>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
    <comment>
        <comment.1/>
        <comment.2/>
        <comment.3/>
    </comment>
</testExecution>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<testExecution>
   <test>
      <test.1/>
      <test.2/>
      <test.3/>
   </test>
   <comment>
      <comment.1/>
      <comment.2/>
      <comment.3/>
   </comment>
   <people>
      <importantPeople>
         <executor>
            <executor.1/>
            <executor.2/>
            <executor.3/>
         </executor>
         <comment>
            <comment.1/>
            <comment.2/>
            <comment.3/>
         </comment>
         <comment>
            <comment.1/>
            <comment.2/>
            <comment.3/>
         </comment>
      </importantPeople>
      <invoker>
         <invoker.1/>
         <invoker.2/>
         <invoker.3/>
      </invoker>
   </people>
   <recipient>
      <recipient.1/>
      <recipient.2/>
      <recipient.3/>
   </recipient>
   <comment>
      <comment.1/>
      <comment.2/>
      <comment.3/>
   </comment>
   <comment>
      <comment.1/>
      <comment.2/>
      <comment.3/>
   </comment>
</testExecution>
```