# xslt generate children based on split and parent node name

Tags: xslt

is it possible to do the following in xsl. I'm tring to split the contents of an element and create sub-elements based on the split. To make things trickier there are the occasional exception (ie node-4 doesn't get split). I'm wondering if there is a way i can do this without explicit splits hardcoded for each element. Again, not sure if this is possible. thanks for the help!

original XML:

```
<document>
  <node>
    <node-1>hello world1</node-1>
    <node-2>hello^world2</node-2>
    <node-3>hello^world3</node-3>
    <node-4>hello^world4</node-4>
  </node>
</document>
```

transformed XML

```
<document>
  <node>
    <node-1>hello world1</node-1>
    <node-2>
      <node2-1>hello</node2-1>
      <node2-2>world2</node2-2>
    </node-2>
    <node-3>
      <node3-1>hello</node3-1>
      <node3-2>world3</node3-2>
    </node-3>
    <node-4>hello^world4</node-4>
  </node>
</document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an XSL 1.0 solution.  I presume that the inconsistency in node-4 in your sample output was just a typo.  Otherwise you'll have to define why node3 was split and node4 wasn't.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <node>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document/node/*"/>
      </node>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="tag" select="name()"/>

    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="contains(text(),'^')">
        <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
          <xsl:element name="{concat($tag,'-1')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(),'^')"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="{concat($tag,'-2')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),'^')"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works as long as all the nodes you want split are at the same level, under `/document/node`.  If the real document structure is different you will have to tweak the solution to match.

Comment: nicely done. thank you. I change it a bit so that you can have N subnodes using a split with foreach and positon(). Thanks again!

Comment: posting my final solution below which uses most of Jims in case anyone is interested

Comment: The question explicity states: *To make things trickier there are the occasional exception (ie node-4 doesn't get split).*

Comment: @Alejandro - Hmm... I don't think that was there earlier. Besides, that would just involve stating the rules and coding the appropriate `select=` and `match=` attributes.  It doesn't invalidate the approach.

Answer (score 2):

> To make things trickier there are the
>   occasional exception (ie node-4
>   doesn't get split). I'm wondering if
>   there is a way i can do this without
>   explicit splits hardcoded for each
>   element.

Pattern matching text nodes to tokenize, this more semantic stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()[contains(.,'^')]" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="pString" select="concat(.,'^')"/>
        <xsl:param name="pCount" select="1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$pString">
            <xsl:element name="{translate(name(..),'-','')}-{$pCount}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pString,'^')"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="pString" 
                                select="substring-after($pString,'^')"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pCount" select="$pCount + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node-4/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<document>
    <node>
        <node-1>hello world1</node-1>
        <node-2>
            <node2-1>hello</node2-1>
            <node2-2>world2</node2-2>
        </node-2>
        <node-3>
            <node3-1>hello</node3-1>
            <node3-2>world3</node3-2>
        </node-3>
        <node-4>hello^world4</node-4>
    </node>
</document>
```

**Note**: A classic tokenizer (In fact, this use a normalized string allowing empty items in sequence). Pattern matching and overwriting rules (preserving `node-4` text node).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use XSLT 2.0? If so, it sounds like [`<xsl:analyze-string>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string) is right up your alley. You can split based on a regexp.

If you need further details, ask...

Answer (score 0):

solution i used:

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node-2 | node-3" name="subFieldCarrotSplitter">
    <xsl:variable name="tag" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:split(text(),'^')">
            <xsl:element name="{concat($tag,'-',position())}">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @user364939: It might be strange for other people the traversing on following axis unless you link previus question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281431/how-can-i-transform-this-using-keys . Also, do check my answer for a classic tokenizer without extensions.